Fuzzy and exact matching using Arrow and Duckdb R
I have a large dataset of over 43 million rows and 3.84 GB and another dataset of over 6000 rows and 459 KB. I am trying to do an inner_join() based on two columns: One exact column based on a common id and the a fuzzy match based on fullname. I tried the following based on the information I found on this post, however I am facing memory issues:
fuzzy_join<-stringdist_join(first_data, second_data, 
                by = "fullname",
                mode = "inner",
                ignore_case = FALSE, 
                method = "jw", 
                max_dist = 0.5) %>% 
  filter(id == id)

The first 10 rows of the datasets using dput(head(df,10))
first_data<- structure(list(user_id = c(441391106, 441514065, 442060539, 442158489, 
438197192, 438206034, 438689594, 438881971, 440386286, 440479235
), fullname = c("Siva Kumar", "Kalyani M", "James Bigler", "Arthur Stephens", 
"guy guy", "Rick Schlieper", "Tony Klemencic", "baiyu xu", "Michael Fritts", 
"Daniel Wolf Roemele"), f_prob = c(0, 1, 0.005, 0.006, 0.005, 
0.002, 0.011, 0.389, 0.005, 0.004), m_prob = c(1, 0, 0.995, 0.994, 
0.995, 0.998, 0.989, 0.611, 0.995, 0.996), white_prob = c(0.021, 
0.001, 0.994, 0.792, 0.547, 0.949, 0.948, 0.001, 0.995, 0.795
), black_prob = c(0.013, 0.003, 0.001, 0.198, 0.398, 0.004, 0.003, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.097), api_prob = c(0.904, 0.991, 0, 0, 0.001, 
0.002, 0.003, 0.994, 0.001, 0.061), hispanic_prob = c(0.005, 
0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0, 0.001, 0.039, 0.001, 0, 0.012), native_prob = c(0.006, 
0.002, 0, 0, 0, 0.005, 0, 0, 0, 0.003), multiple_prob = c(0.051, 
0.002, 0.004, 0.008, 0.054, 0.039, 0.007, 0.003, 0.003, 0.032
), degree = c("", "", "Bachelor", "", "", "Master", "Associate", 
"", "", ""), other_id = c(1212616, 1212616, 1212616, 1212616, 1212991, 
1212991, 1212991, 1212991, 1212991, 1212991), id = c(62399, 
62399, 62399, 62399, 63907, 63907, 63907, 63907, 63907, 63907
)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

second_data<- structure(list(id = c(12825, 12945, 12945, 12945, 16456, 16456, 
16456, 12136, 12136, 17254), another_id = c(7879, 8587, 18070, 40634, 
13142, 17440, 41322, 899, 27199, 26604), fname = c("Gerald", 
"John", "Dean", "Todd", "Thomas", "Ivan", "Vinit", "Scott", "Jonathan", 
"William"), mname = c("B.", "L.", "A.", "P.", "F.", "R.", 
"K.", "G.", "I.", "Jensen"), lname = c("Shreiber", "Nussbaum", 
"Foate", "Kelsey", "Kirk", "Sabel, CPO", "Asar", "McNealy", "Schwartz", 
"Gedwed"), companyname = c(NA, "Plexus Corp.", "Plexus Corp.", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "Oracle America, Inc.", "Oracle America, Inc.", 
NA), fullname = c("Gerald Shreiber", "John Nussbaum", 
"Dean Foate", "Todd Kelsey", "Thomas Kirk", "Ivan Sabel", "Vinit Asar", 
"Scott McNealy", "Jonathan Schwartz", "William Gedwed")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Is there a solution using duckdb and arrow to do this simultaneous fuzzy and exact join?
This post specifies the use of these two packages for merging large datasets, however, I am not sure how to apply it to this current question.
